# Github Windows client detects cpp file as binary file

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm having a small problem with using the Windows client for Github. I have a file in my repository which is named "dllmain.cpp" for which it says, when I click on it, "This binary file has changed". So  for some reason it detects it as a binary file instead of a code file, meaning it does not track the code changes. 
My only thought is that it could be because of the "dll" in the name, but I assume it should check the file extension and not the file name.

Is there any way to fix this so I can make it detect it as a .cpp file instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add it in your `.gitattribute` file as text.

But identification as binary is not based on file name or extension. You should propably have a look on your cpp file and its encoding. There might be some special characters in, maybe non-printable.